# Can i download my own paid app in alpha testing?

Tags: android, google-play

I published my paid application but now I want to test my application in alpha mode before launch new update on google play.

So, Is it possible to publish my application in alpha mode and I can download the application for testing purpose without paying?

If anyone have idea...please reply.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can publish your alpha or beta-test APK and you can select a group of users to test.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for reply, My question is that i already published a paid application.But i want to test in alpha mode but without paying and want to download my own account.

Comment: You can move your production app back to the alpha stage, but I'm not sure if you'll be able to download it without paying for.

Comment: @soulreaver, Thanks for reply,I don't want to back to alpha mode.But i want to upgrate the version after alpha testing.

Comment: You cannot download without paying.

Answer (score 0):

Under Profile Settings on Developer Console go down to LVL Test accounts and add you email address and set to LICENSED/VALID signal.

It will work :D